# How would I run a program while not breaking the bot?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

So as the code goes as below, I want to be able to make my bot run a second python program when a certain phrase is said. Such as

> can you start a webcam bot?

etc. etc. I just need something that calls the python file with the script in it, and like I said, not cause the bot to close.

Code as follows

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.training.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

# Create a new instance of a ChatBot
bot = ChatBot("NOSTAW",
storage_adapter="chatterbot.adapters.storage.JsonDatabaseAdapter",
logic_adapters=[
    "chatterbot.adapters.logic.MathematicalEvaluation",
    "chatterbot.adapters.logic.TimeLogicAdapter",
    "chatterbot.adapters.logic.ClosestMatchAdapter"
],
input_adapter="chatterbot.adapters.input.TerminalAdapter",
output_adapter="chatterbot.adapters.output.TerminalAdapter",
database="../SecondaryDataBase.json"
)
bot.set_trainer(ChatterBotCorpusTrainer)

# Train the chat bot with the entire english corpus
bot.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")

print("Type thoughts to bot.")

# The following loop will execute each time the user enters input
while True:
try:
    # We pass None to this method because the parameter
    # is not used by the TerminalAdapter
    bot_input = bot.get_response(None)

# Press ctrl-c or ctrl-d on the keyboard to exit
except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
    break
```

If anyone could help, please post the code, and some sites I could learn further about this topic. Thank you.

Comment: You should import that other file using the `import` statement and treat it like a module. This will allow you access to the functions and classes defined in that file. If the code in the other file isn't factored into functions and classes, then you should probably refactor. If you really must fork off a process, look into the multiprocessing library

Comment: You seemed to have answered twice, oh well. I'll try and do the one below, since I have it all on my usb drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hack will do the what you are looking for

```
os.system("python otherfile.py")
```